# Sugar ORM, List all in Kotlin? Java works, but Kotlin does not

Tags: kotlin, sugarorm

The following Java code seems to be fine (no IDE errors),

```
List<Job> jobs = Job.listAll(Job.class);
```

When I copy-and-pasted, it was translated into,

```
val jobs = Job.listAll<Job>(Job::class.java)
```

But there was an error. Unresolved reference; listAll. What is the correct Kotlin equivalent?

The data class

```
import com.orm.SugarRecord

class Job : SugarRecord()
{
```

Sugar ORM: https://github.com/chennaione/sugar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not work because child class in Kotlin does not inherit static method from parent. (`static` does not exist in Kotlin)

You call the method like this:

```
SugarRecord.listAll(Job::class.java)
```